# IF Statements with XML in NetSuite

Tags: html, css, xml, netsuite

I am trying to include a conditional IF statement on the Advanced PDF/HTML Template in NetSuite. This statement will display '0' if the ${line.amountremaining} is equal to the ${line.payment}. This is the table that I have:

[image]

Thank you for your help in advance!

I have tried including the IF statement like below but it doesn't work. It is printing the entire statement on the output.

[image]

Comment: Second, please post your code instead of an image.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the if statement is incorrect. Please see below.

```
<#if $line.amountremaining == ${line.payment}>
${line.amountremaining} == 0;
<#else>
//Else statement here
</#if>
```

Please take the time to read through the Freemarker documentation on if statements: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_if.html